# how do I backup logins and jobs from SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there a script or function in sqlserver2005 that i can backup the jobs and login details of a server from the master database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jobs are stored in the [MSDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187112.aspx) database and logins in the [Master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx) database.

You can backup these system databases as you would any other of your user databases. Use the Management Studio GUI or via the ["backup database.." TSQL syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx).

See this article on [backing up your system databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190190.aspx). With specific considerations for the [backing up master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191488.aspx) and [backing up MSDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188274.aspx).